# Is there a simple php compatible video chat service?

Tags: php, video, chat

I have a client that has an existing CMS and he'd like to pair two of his members at a time to engage in video chat for a tutoring service. Is there a service out there that is php-compatible that would allow for a seamless integration, meaning that the user wont have to create a 2nd account with the video chat provider?

Edit: yes, I know there's a lot of SO questions on video chat, and I've read about 50 of them and all of them seem to be trying to do the whole thing on their own. I'm looking for a solution where all we do is use an API or something like that to connect two users via video chat.

Comment: PHP wouldn't handle video chat. Flash or possibly JavaScript would do this.

Comment: Right, flash handles the video chat, but I need to be able to choose which two members are chatting with each other and put the video chat box on a page that is generated using php.

Comment: There is service from dimdim .Please refer to this link .They have an api . But they charge for the service http://www.dimdim.com/

Comment: Aparently, dimdim.com got acquired by salesforce and no longer offers its service :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://streamapi.com/

https://watershed.ustream.tv/ and also a list you might find handy: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2008/08/07/40-video-apis-on-programmableweb/

I just googled for "video streaming api"